# How to display a nav ul list as a select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm busy working on a responsive mobile first site and one of the requirements is to display the main navigation (nav>ul>li) like it would be a  tag for the mobile view. I've in the past used either javascript to display it on click or just kept it inline depending on the client, but haven't had this requirement before, so I'm wondering if there is a way with CSS to have the `<li>` display like it would if it were a `<select>` tag. For desktop view it will just display normally inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have separate elements for nav and select like below.

```
<select id="mobileNav">
    <option>your links</option>
</select>
```

and your original nav

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li>links</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Now in your CSS use media queries to toggle based on screen width:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   nav {
   display: none;
  }
   select#mobileNav {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
   select#mobileNav {
     display: none;
   }
      nav {
     display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that seemed to work fine. I think that would be cool if they added it to the CSS3 spec that you can display it as a <select>, because I've noticed a few sites now doing it and we already have display as table, etc. That said though, this works awesome. Thanks very much!